# DITA Transformation (PDF) to Include Child Elements from Missing Parent Elements

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, xsl-fo, apache-fop, dita

I am trying to publish DITA projects for localization purposes. The client is only supplying partial sets of XML as DITA references along with the main map that includes lots of other content that is not being provided.

We used to publish those maps as PDFs in Arbortext with Styler, and somehow its embedded FOP engine managed to resolve those missing chapters and even included subsections (which is VERY important) of those missing XML chapters when the chapters themselves were not provided. It took the names of them from the map and used it as the chapter header in the output.

Oftentimes, like I mentioned above, in a book of 10-12 chapters 1500+ pages, 5 out of 12 chapters (by chapters I mean XML files that are included into the map as a chapter) are not supplied by the client because there were no updates in them and there is no need to translate them. However, they still supply updated references that are included into those chapters.

Whenever I am trying to publish such a project in Arbortext, it outputs all the content whether or not some portions of it are listed in the map as part of chapters that are missing in the folder.

However, when I am trying to publish the same project in oXygen, it skips all subsections of the missing chapters completely outputting 20-40% of the whole book.

Is there anything quick and simple that can be changed in the DITA processing instructions for oXygen/stylesheet/Antenna House options so that oXygen did the same as what happening in Arbortext when missing chapters are still included into the output in the form of the filenames for the missing XMLs and the subsections are there too included into those missing chapters?

Transformation in oXygen 15.2 are set to be run with Antenna House v6.4. Both tech support engineers from oXygen (Radu) and Antenna House know of no simple fix to this other than creation of empty missing XML files temporarily. Yet, the amount of daily projects and the number of the missing chapters are far too large to process this manually.

What really bothers me is that Arbortext 6.2 is somehow able to produce complete PDFs from incomplete projects even with multiple missing XML files. Yet, it hiccups quite a bit during the transformation, yes, it gives me lots of warnings, yet it still spits out a well-composed PDFs with filenames instead of actual files where such files are missing - which is totally fine with me.

I was told that this is somehow and for some reason not possible to replicate in oXygen.

Any ideas how to overcome this and publish all the content whether or not some portions of it are listed in the map as part of sections for which XML files are not provided?

Thank you,

Ilia

Comment: Can you clarify what FO processor you actually use? Saying "FOP for oXygen 15.2 is Antenna House v6.4" is confusing. FOP is a specific FO processor as is Antenna House. And then you also mention Arbortext.

Comment: oXygen comes with a build-in FO Processor (Apache FOP), but we were required to reproduce the client's environment and import their global options for oXygen they supplied us with. 

The client is using Antenna House for all their transformation scenarios. This formatter processor was purchased, configured in the system with all environment variables, and set up in oXygen accordingly. It is able to produce PDFs yet is missing out those child elements that are included into the missing parent elements in the map. Hope I was able to answer your question.

Comment: If you don't actually use Apache FOP in this scenario, you shouldn't tag the question with "fop" and "apache-fop". Use the "xsl-fo" tag instead. Also, the question is rather broad. How can we reproduce the problem you are describing?

Comment: The reason I referred to Apache FOP was because it is acting the same way as AH should I switch to it and complete the same transformation scenario, so naturally I argue that Apache FOP community is larger than that of Antenna House, which is rather an expensive commercial product. Considering the fact that both the above give me the same output I do not see why I should have restricted the tags and not include fop or apache-fop if the two act similarly and if I wanted to reach the broader audience. In any case, this is all off-topic.

Comment: Naturally, there is no simple way to reproduce the issue unless you reproduce the environment and have the project files with the customized global settings and DITA-OT framework. All I am interested in is the direction to go for and if there is a conceptually simple way to resolve it since Arbortext is able to place the filenames of the missing chapters in place of the missing chapters content itself, which allows it to include child elements of those chapters. My question was rather if the same can be achieved in oXygen with a relatively simple revision in the DITA-OT/xslt/etc.